# I want to create graph with nodes as in the image:

Tags: tables, xy-pic, graphs

[image]

I wrote an example graph with `\xymatrix` - that's OK. I added circles with &*+[Fo], that's OK too. I added table inside first circle with `\begin{tabular}` - it is OK. But table needs to be rotated by -45 degrees. When i use isorot package to rotate it, first - it rotates not against center, but against corner, and, more sadly, xymatrix then can't determine circle size, and it shrinks.

How can I rotate table in next example?

```
$$\xymatrix{&*+[Fo]{
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
2&3\\
\hline
4&5
\end{tabular}
}\ar@{-}[r]\ar@{-}[dd]\ar@{-}[rrd]&*+[Fo]{3}\ar@{-}[lld]\ar@{-}[ldd]\ar@{-}[dd]\ar@{-}[rdd]\ar@{-}[rd]& \\ *+[Fo]{1}\ar@{-}[rrr] &&&*+[Fo]{4}\ar@{-}[ld] \\ &*+[Fo]{7}&*+[Fo]{6}\ar@{-}[l]&*+[Fo]{5}& }$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not say that you are required to use `xy-pic`, even though you used it, here's a TikZ suggestion. I use TikZ for such diagrams since it's very capable and the readably syntax is a great benefit for making complex diagrams.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\newcommand*{\drawnode}[1]{
  \draw (#1.45) -- (#1.225);
  \draw (#1.135) -- (#1.315);
  \node at ( $ (#1) + (90:0.5cm)  $ ) {1};
  \node at ( $ (#1) + (180:0.5cm) $ ) {2};
  \node at ( $ (#1) + (0:0.5cm)   $ ) {3};
  \node at ( $ (#1) + (270:0.5cm) $ ) {4};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=2.5 cm, >=angle 60,
  splittednode/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1.5 cm},
  every node/.append style={font=\sffamily}]

\node[splittednode] (A) {};
\node[splittednode, above right of =A,] (B) {};
\node[splittednode, below right of =A,] (C) {};

\foreach \Node in {A,B,C}
  \drawnode{\Node};

\draw[->] (A) -- node{10} (B);
\draw[->] (A) -- node{20} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: Well, i shall try it tomorrow. But one question - how can i draw an arror not DIRECT to right or up, or something. Say, i want to arrow up, then right, then right again, then down, and here i want to place node? And second question - can i make two arrows to same node?

Comment: @user2031702 You can post this as a new question. Comments are not the best place for discussing follow-up questions. This Q&A site works best with one question for each problem.

Comment: @user2031702 Nice to read! So you use TikZ for this now? I would add the tikz-pgf tag after specifying in the question that TikZ would be an option, besides xy-pic. It would be great if you would mark the answer as accepted, by clicking the check mark at the left.